# TFS 2017 update2 custom page under work item not added by Plugin

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I new to TFS and VSTS and created a plugin for VSTS and TFS which contribute to work item group and hub group. Its works fine for VSTS but in TFS 2017 update2 it is not showing custom page for work item.
Code which is used by me.

```
"contributions": [
 {
     "id": "custom-sample-work-item-form-page",
     "type": "ms.vss-work-web.work-item-form-page",
     "description": "Adds Execution Result to the Work Item form group",
     "targets": [
              "ms.vss-work-web.work-item-form"
      ],
      "properties": {
             "name": "My Custom Page",
             "uri": "index.html",
             "height": 600
         }

      },
```

What is the root cause for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's only applied to VSTS by installing the extension directly. See [Configure contributions in work item form](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/develop/add-workitem-extension#configure-contributions-in-work-item-form).

> In VSTS, by default the group extensions will appear in the end of the
>   second column of the form and page contributions will appear after all
>   the work item form pages as a tab. Control contributions are not shown
>   in the form by default so users will have to manually add them to the
>   form. In TFS, to show/hide or move the control, group and page
>   contributions in work item form, see [Configure work item form
>   extensions in TFS](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/develop/configure-workitemform-extensions).

So ,for TFS on-premise, you need to **add an extension tag** in the specific work item definition (xml) file.

1. Export the work item definition file :

   `witadmin exportwitd /collection:CollectionURL /p:Project /n:TypeName /f:FileName`
2. Open the xml file and find your **extension ID** in the "**Work Item Extensions**" section
3. Add an extension tag below the "Work Item Extensions" section as
   shown below to make your extension available to the work item form.

   `<Extensions>
           <Extension Id="example.color-control-dev" />
     </Extensions>`
4. Save and import this .xml file.

   `witadmin importwitd /collection:CollectionURL /p:Project /f:FileName`

See [Add extensions in work item form via work item type definition xml](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/develop/configure-workitemform-extensions) for details.

---

**UPDAET:**

If you need to add the tab for all the work item types, you can create a script to export/import the definition xml files. Also bulk add the extension tag with text editor such as Notepad++.

For example:

```
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE
witadmin exportwitd /collection:http://server:8080/tfs/CollectionLC /f:E:\CustomeWIT\Task.xml /p:TFVC-Scrum
witadmin exportwitd /collection:http://server:8080/tfs/CollectionLC /f:E:\CustomeWIT\PBI.xml /p:TFVC-Scrum
```

...

```
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE
witadmin importwitd /collection:http://server:8080/tfs/CollectionLC /f:E:\CustomeWIT\Task.xml /p:TFVC-Scrum
witadmin importwitd /collection:http://server:8080/tfs/CollectionLC /f:E:\CustomeWIT\PBI.xml /p:TFVC-Scrum
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Andy for your response, but i think it is not  a generic solution if i give my extension to a client. For each work item we have to repeat these steps. Is there any generic solution for achieving this.

Comment: @NitinParashar Unfortunately, this is the official solution, for now we cannot  achieve that as VSTS. See the updated answer. But you can create a script to export/import all the work item definition files.

Comment: Can u provide me any link that says about, this an official solution.

Comment: @NitinParashar Just the first link in above updated answer,quoted text. Anyway, see this link : [Configure contributions in work item form](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/develop/add-workitem-extension#configure-contributions-in-work-item-form)