# Adding new "tab" to a bug work item in TFS 2017

Tags: tfs

I am trying to add a new "tab" to bug item in TFS 2017.  Looking at the "tabs" you see things like "Steps to Reproduce", System, etc.  [image: Screen shot showing what I am talking about]

I have found information on changing work item types but nothing about adding a new "tab" across the top where you see Steps to Repro, System, Test Cases, Tasks.  The change I want to make may not be possible?  Or it is possible I don't know the correct verbiage to use when asking google. The think I want to change may not be a tab control at all it maybe something else different.

Thanks

***************** Updated questions after posting *****************************
After playing around with Process Editor -> WIT -> Open WIT from server -> Bug 
as suggested by  Andy Li-MSFT I don't see a lot of control on the formatting on the tab.  I was planning to add fields in a grid like pattern like a table as shown below.  I am able to get the values in the drop down list for field1 and add the fields.  However I have a couple follow up questions if you have time.

1. Setting either the control or column for the control to read-only the column will not render when adding a new bug.  I have a little more control if I set AllowedValues and Frozen for the column however the value can still be changed. Is there a better way to set read-only?
2. There is not much control on the layout.  I am OK adding a lot of fields but would like them to be displayed in a table like structure.  Is there a way to control the look of the fields on the form?
3. Is there a way to add the fields in a grid?  This would be ideal so I only have one header for each column.
4. The last-updated-by and last-updated-date.  Is it possible to track on a row level who made a change?  If not I would be OK just adding a last updated by and last updated date to the new tab.  Row level updates would be nice.

```html
<pre>

Field 1    Field 2  (Read-only)    Field 3   Last Updated By  Last updated Date
Status (completed, empty, N/A)  "Some text here which describes something to do" "Optional comments" tfs user name  date/time 
Status (completed, empty, N/A)  "Some text here which describes something to do" "Optional comments" tfs user name  date/time 


</pre>
```

Comment: You need to modify the process template. That should give you the information you need to effectively search for how to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify the WIT definition file (**Bug** work item type in your scenario).

You can try below ways to do that:

1. Export the WIT definition file with `witadmin` commands, add a new tab under `<TabGroup>` and add a new control for it, then save and import the file. See [Import, export, and manage work item types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/customize/reference/witadmin/witadmin-import-export-manage-wits?view=tfs-2018) for details.

e.g:

```
<Tab Label="Tab0501">
     <Control FieldName="System.ChangedDate" Type="DateTimeControl" Label="Test0501:" LabelPosition="Left" />
</Tab>
```

2. You can also use the **TFS Power Tools** to export/import WIT definition files or directly modify the files from server:

   Visual Studio 2015 : [Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server
   2015 Power Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TFSPowerToolsTeam.MicrosoftVisualStudioTeamFoundationServer2015Power)

   Visual Studio 2017 : [TFS Process Template Editor](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=KarthikBalasubramanianMSFT.TFSProcessTemplateEditor)

   ***Reference below screenshot to do that***.
3. Another way is writing an extension to [Extend the work item form](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/vsts/extend/develop/add-workitem-extension?view=vsts#add-a-page), you can reference [**my answer in another**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46048371/7466674) thread to do that.

[image]

Comment: @user8916597 Have you resolved the issue by above answer? any update?

Comment: I have been tied up on something else and plan to look at it today.

Comment: This was very helpful and answers the question I asked. After playing around using your instructions I am not sure what I want to do is possible?  The plan was to add a new tab with fields that can be populated.  However looking at formatting there does not seem to be an easy way because everything is down the left side of the new form.  I have updated my original post with with a few follow up questions if you have time.  I will mark your response as the accepted answer.

Comment: @user8916597 Based on the rule on SO, one thread one question. I suggest you creating new threads to track the new/followup questions, thus you can get the responses quickly from communities and helpful for solving problems more effectively. Also this can be beneficial to other community members reading this thread.

Comment: @user8916597 Whatever, short answer for your followup questions: Q1. Based on the existing read-only rule, we can only read it and cannot modify/edit it **manually**, but the values will be changed following the control/system settings, e.g. status change, modified time change etc. No other better ways unless you set a plain text box which does not rely on other controls. Q2 and Q3: No, we can only custom the WIT based on the existing structure of the definition file. Cannot create table or grid. You can try to create a new group or column.

Comment: @user8916597 Q4: Actually you can track that from the **History** tab (Near by Details).

Comment: @user8916597 Since the original issue was resolved by the solution, could you please Accept it as an Answer, This can be beneficial to other community members reading this thread. If you still have doubts for the followup questions, you can open new threads, we will response that in time.

Comment: I tried that the other day when I accepted your answer.  I did not realize the check box was how to mark the answer as the accepted answer.  I tried clicking the up arrow to say the answer was helpful.